# Dual Boot /mnt/boot/ is too full

Tags: boot, partition, dual-boot

I want to install arch-linux alongside my Windows. I've done this some times already since I kinda like reinstalling a fresh system every now and then.

But now I have the problem that my boot partition is too full. Whenever I install Linux I mark the partition for booting without formating so that I don't delete my Windows boot manager.

But my last installation failed because this partition seems too have no space left. Is there a way to easily remove the old stuff on the boot partition without deleting the Windows boot manager? 
Or do I have to cleanup the whole disk and reinstall Windows afterwards?

Comment: Can you list which files are in your /boot?

Comment: As root or with sudo `parted -l`